# Apache : Apache not respecting ErrorDocument directive, still get default 503 error page

Tags: apache, tomcat, server

We have a Spring-MVC application running simultaneously on 2 Apache tomcats, which are load-balanced by Apache Web server with mod_jk. We have such a setup on 2 servers, and on the 2nd server the ErrorDocument directive is being respected, but not on the first one. If I shut down tomcats, and then try to access the page, I am getting the default 503 error page, and not the customized one which I have placed in /var/www (Document root). Please note that the entire webapp runs under `https`.

000-default :

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html
</Directory>
JkMount /* loadbalancer
SSLEngine on
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


root@domain /var/www # ls 
maintenance.html
```

If there is anything more required, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Well, is the 503 coming from the backend? Probably it is, if Apache is not giving an error there is no reason to not show the errordocument for 503. If you were using mod_proxy you could at least use ProxyErrorOverride. With mod_jk, I don't know.

Comment: @ezra-s : I am using mod_jk! Error is coming from Apache web server. So, if tomcat is down, apache cannot complete the redirection and says 503.

Comment: Then add a ErrorLog directive and for each virtualhost and check the errorlog file to make sure, an error is always logged and then ErrorDocument should kick in. Also, do not use Directory / <-- that is the / of your filesystem, and do not use AllowOverride All, becuase .htaccess files will overwrite what you defined in VirtualHost.

Comment: @ezra-s : I dont have a .htaccess file, and I removed the directory block, no change. Any ideas?

Comment: @ezra-s : I am getting this as a response : Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.. I have added a ProxyPass to the maintenance html, but that also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JkMount /*` which includes everything.

Use a less restrictive path or exclude /maintenance.html with mod_jk directives.

Comment: Will test this thing in morning and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Just tried JkUnmount directive, didn't help, here is what I tried, `JkUnMount /maintenance/* loadbalancer JkUnMount /maintenance/* jk-status` . I have moved the maintenance.html inside a maintenance folder created in /var/www/